# A general term for 'how positive/negative is this result'

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, category

I am running a series of tests, each of which has one of several possible results: *Negative*, *Positive*, *Detected*, *Not Detected*, *Equivocal*, etc.

I need to group these into results which are 'generally positive' (*Positive*, *Detected*), 'generally negative' (*Negative*, *Not Detected*) and 'neutral/other' (*Equivocal* and others).

For example:

> In order to collate the results, I cross-check each result's **(something)** against the list of **(somethings)**.

My question is, what do I label that grouping of Negative/Positive/Other? A single word would be ideal, but a compound word could work. A phrase won't work, as this needs to be used as a compact label. A good solution will be somewhat intuitive, though it can be technical if need be.

Words I've considered:

- *Type*, *Category*, *Kind* (all too generic)
- *Sign* (drawing too heavily from electrical positive/negative),
- *Valence* (probably the best I've come up with, but a bit obscure and un-intuitive).

Comment: Your title and your post seem to be asking two different questions.

Comment: How about "score"?

Comment: @HotLicks I feel like 'score' implies a numerical value, rather than a categorical one.

Comment: So, give numbers to the categories.

Comment: I think that's just moving the problem around: Q: Why is it called 'score'? - A: Because the values have numbers. Q: Why do they have numbers? ...

Comment: Maybe you cross-check each result against the list of possibilities.

Comment: @Jim - I'm looking for a label for the particular aspect (positive/negative/other) of the result I am checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have used **[Disposition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disposition#synonyms)**, in the sense of the 'prevailing tendency' of a thing. I'm not sure it's the best, but at the least it's neutral and doesn't introduce any false 'clues' about its meaning.

Comment: 'Outcome' is far more idiomatic, is unmarked for 'positiveness' etc, and is hardly less generic than 'disposition' (which I'd say has an unwanted nuance, from its primary sense,  itself).

Comment: Outcome is excellent, @EdwinAshworth. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: It's generic to the nth, idiomatic squared, and probably not credibility-maintaining enough for ELU.